# Pi boots to rainbow screen and flashing RED LED when using BerryBoot

Tags: retropie, pi-3b+, berryboot

I recently bought a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+. As I want Raspbian together with Retropie I thought it would be a good idea to have the BerryBoot-bootloader in order to boot multiple operating systems. I thought about NOOBS also, but this doesn't seem work well with RetroPie.

So I followed [these instructions](https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/boot-multiple-operating-systems-raspberry-pi-with-berryboot-0177483/) to load BerryBoot, but when I plug the Pi's power-supply it keeps showing the rainbow-screen:

1. format SD-card as of https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/sdxc_formatting.md using SD-formatter first and guiformat.exe afterwards
2. unzip the BerryBoot-file into the freshly formatted cards root-directory
3. plug keyboard, LAN-cable and HDMI-cable into PI
4. plug powersupply

This is my setup:

- Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ 1,4 GHz 64Bit Quad Core
- Samsung microSDXC EVO 64GB, UHS-I/Class 10
- official 5,1V/2,5A power-supply for Raspberry Pi 3 Model B white
- [BerryBoot from SourceFourge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/berryboot/files/berryboot-20170509-pi2-pi3.zip/)

I'm not sure if this is related to the question, but there's also a small lightning-icon in the upper right corner of the screen. Also the Pi's red LED blinks four times long followed by four times short.

I'm beginner on Pi, so I'm not sure which of those information belongs together or should go to different topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rainbow-screen is normally an indication of old/unsupported firmware.

BerryBoot is not really a beginners tool, and (at least last time I tried it) has a number of restrictions (e.g need for common kernel) about supported OS.

If you **REALLY** need multi-boot I suggest you try 
[PINN](https://github.com/procount/pinn/blob/master/README_PINN.md) (this is an upgraded NOOBS which supports more OS and is a lot more flexible).

SD Cards are cheap enough that it is better to use one per OS - after all you can only run one at a time, and swapping SD Cards is easy.

Comment: I also read about PINN. But as of https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=170263 PINN seems to supply only an older verson of RetroPie. Anyway, it´not that SD-cards would be expensive, it´s just I don´t want to exchange the card everytime I want to switch the OS. But I´ll try PINN anyway. Thanks.